# Linear algorithm of finding tree diameter

Tags: algorithm, tree

I have the following code to find the diameter of a tree:

```
ALGORITHM: TREE_DIAMETER (T)

maxlength ← 0
for s ← 0 to s < |V[T]|
      do temp ← BSF(T, S)
            if maxlength < temp
                   maxlength ← temp
                   increment s by 1
return maxlength
```

But this algorithm does not run in linear time. Preserving the details of the above code as much as possible (Eg: using BSF), is it possible to optimize it to linear time? You can use pseudo-code.

Comment: What does BFS(T, S) exactly return? What is S(the second argument of BFS)?

Comment: the title is really confusing: there's no recursion at all but you want a linear algorithm.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a simple algorithm with linear time complexity:
1)Pick an arbitrary vertex `v`.
2)Find the furthest vertex from `v` using BFS(let's call it `u`).
3)Find the furthest vertex from `u` using BFS one more time(let's call it `t`).
Then `distance(u, t)` is the diameter.
BFS is called only twice, so the time complexity is linear.

Comment: It's definitely linear time.  Now prove it's correct.

Comment: Proof of the above algorithm(exercise 9-1) http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.046/fall01/handouts/ps9sol.pdf

Answer (score 12):

As supplementary to the other answer, a proof can be done as follow:

Let's first denote the two ends of the diameter in the tree as `s` and `t`, and the function `d(u, v)` denotes the distance between node `u` and node `v`.

Now we choose an arbitrary node `X`, then we have 2 cases:

1. `X` is on the diameter;
2. `X` is **not** on the diameter.

For case 1, it's easy to see that by doing (2) (the second step in the algorithm described in @user2040251's answer), we will get either `d(X, s)` or `d(X, t)`. If we get something else, say `d(X, u)`, then `u` and `s` or `t` can form a longer path than `d(s, t)`, which contradicts the fact. Therefore, by doing (3), we will get `d(s, t)`.

For case 2, by doing (2), we have 2 cases:

1. The longest path starting from `X` contains at least 1 point on the diameter;
2. The longest path starting from `X` doesn't share **any** points with the diameter.

For case 2.1, let's denote the **first intersection** as `Y`. Because of case 1, we know the longest path starting from `Y` **must end at either `s` or `t`**. Therefore, in this case, the longest path starting from `X` must end at either `s` or `t`. Consequently, by doing (3), we will get `d(s, t)`.

For case 2.2, let's denote the other end of the longest path starting from `X` as `Z`. Since neither `X` or `Z` is on the diameter, and given `X`, `Z`, `s`, `t` are on the same tree, we can conclude that there **must be a node `V` on the path `X` to `Z`, links to a node `W` on the path `s` to `t`**. Because `X` to `Z` is the longest path starting from `X`, so `d(X, V) + d(V, W) + d(W, t) < d(X, Z)`. Similarly, we have `d(Z, V) + d(V, W) + d(W, s) < d(X, Z)`. Adding them up and simplify will give us: `d(X, Z) > 2d(V, W) + d(s, t) > d(s, t)`, which contradicts with the fact that `s` to `t` is the diameter.

A graph that illustrates case 2.2:

```
s             Z
|             |
|             |
|             |
W-------------V
|             |
|             |
|             |
t             X
```

So we have:

`d(X, V) + d(V, W) + d(W, t) < d(X, Z)` because `X` to `Z` is the longest path starting from `X`;

`d(Z, V) + d(V, W) + d(W, s) < d(X, Z)` because `X` to `Z` is the longest path starting from `Z`;

Adding up 2 expressions:

`d(X, Z) + 2d(V, W) + d(s, t) < 2d(X, Z)`

Finally, we have `d(X, Z) > 2d(V, W) + d(s, t) > d(s, t)`, which contradicts the fact.

Comment: The reason for `d(Z, V) + d(V, W) + d(W, s) < d(X, Z)` should be `X` to `Z` is the longest path starting from `Z`, NOT `X`.

Comment: @YuxuanChen yup you are right :) it's a typo, and has been fixed. Thanks!