# Adding an edge to a tree graph so as the new maximum distance between any two vertices is minimum possible

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, shortest-path

I have been trying to solve the following problem (mind you, this is no homework, I´m just practicing for an exam using assignments from the last years class) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2OtS.png.

I would like for someone to verify or improve my approach to this task, as I am not really sure whether there is a faster way (or if what I have done is correct at all, really).

My solution:

1) First, I calculate distances between every single telescope (using Pythagorean theorem), giving me an O(V^2) complexity procedure, but it is not that bad, considering the max value of V is 300. I construct a complete graph using these weighted edges.

2) Next, I find the minimum spanning tree of this graph using Kruskal's algorithm, running at an O(E log(V)) complexity.

(this is where I am not sure)

3) As this is a tree graph, I can find its center, ignoring the edge weights.

4) Once I have found the center (considering a single-vertex center, have not thought about what to do with a two-vertex  center too much yet), I divide this graph into subgraphs ( one subgraph related to each edge coming out of the center)

5) For each vertex, i calculate its distance from the center (taking weights into account) - O(E) complexity

6) For each subgraph, take two vertices with largest distance from the center - around O(V log(V)) complexity

7) Take all pairs of vertices obtained this way, and take the max two from these again. If they are not in the same subgraph, we are done, and connnect these two with the new edge.

8) If they are in the same subgraph, go to 3), and run this recursively on the subgraph.

My question is - is this the fastest solution I can achieve? And more importantly, is it even correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, your algorithm does not produce the correct answer.

Please consider the first example that is on the screenshot of the exercise sheet that you have provided. There you have 7 vertices, let's number them from 1 to 7 in the order they are given. I agree that the telescope network is initially a minimum spanning tree, since "the total length of all cables is minimum possible" is stated in the description.

The following edges are the edges of this MST that I have worked out (using the suggested numbering on the vertices):

```
{1,3}, {2,3}, {3,4}, {4,5}, {4,6}, {6,7}
```

Using your way of finding the center, the center is the vertex 4 as every other vertex is at most 2 hops away from it. Now let's divide the MST into its subgraphs as you proposed. There are 3 subgraphs (I use their set of vertices to identify them):

1. {1,2,3}
2. {5}
3. {6,7}

Hence, the vertices that are farthest away from the center are

```
{2,5,7}
```

Cleary, the distance is highest from vertex 2 to vertex 7. I have worked out a distance of 9.99 = sqrt(10) + 2 + sqrt(8) + 2 using the Pythagorean Theorem. As you suggested, your solution is to connect vertex 2 and vertex 7 to minimize the diameter.

But there is a better solution: connect vertex 3 and vertex 7 (as given as solution in the exercise). The reason for this is that the distance from vertex 1 to vertex 7 decreases from 9.06 = sqrt(5) + 2 + sqrt(8) + 2 down to 8.82 = sqrt(10) + sqrt(32). Using your solution, the minimum distance from vertex 1 to vertex 7 would still be 9.06, which does not achieve best possible.

---

Secondly there is no need for a recursion as you suggested in step 8. It is a tree, so how could one of the three subgraphs be connected to another on a route not leading through the center? If they were, the graph would contain a cycle, as the subgraphs are already connected via the center.

---

Thirdly, on dense graphs its better to use Prim-Dijkstra for the MST which achieves *O*(E + Vlog(v)). It is very easy to implement and you can look it up at wikipedia for example. I think that you know it already though.

---

Finally, how to produce the correct result?

As you saw, it is not obvious how to use heuristics to find the edge, since your idea did not work out.

What is the naive solution?
You have almost every vertex pair to choose from, i.e. *O*(n^2) many candidate edges. To to compute its diameter (naively) you need *O*(n^2). So you could try every single edge and compute the diameter of the tree with this additional edge inserted. In the end, you output the minimum diameter. This would be *O*(n^2 * n^2) = *O*(n^4).

How can we do better? I like considering the naive solution first, because you get an idea what things you need to look at. And from there you start to remove unnecessary operations. What you have spotted correctly is that the longest path needs to become shorter (otherwise the diameter would not change). In other words, the edge that you add has to connect two vertices that lie on the longest path. However you don't know which two. You can easily construct examples where every vertex is part of the longest path, but for a nicely distributed network of telescopes there are much fewer vertices on the longest path. Now you only try to insert edges along the longest path and compute the new diameter again in *O*(n^2). If you have k vertices on the longest path you get *O*(n^2 k^2).

In summary:

1. Compute the spanning tree using Prim's algorithm -> *O*(n^2) on your complete graph
2. Compute the longest path, i.e. the diameter, of the tree -> *O*(n^2) to get all k vertices on the longest path
3. Try adding each of the (O(k^2) many) edges between all pairs of vertices on this longest path one at a time and store the minimum over all diameters, i.e. you have to recompute the diameter again and again  (*O*(n^2)). In total: *O*(n^2 k^2)

It would be nice if we could improve on the time to compute the diameter. For trees this works in linear time, see [Linear algorithm of finding tree diameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649166/linear-algorithm-of-finding-tree-diameter). Your graph is initially a tree, but then you add at most a single edge at a time, i.e. it's still almost a tree. So all you need to do is finding the two nodes u1, v1 that are most distant in the original tree and then when inserting an edge e={**u**,v} in our algorithm you remove a different edge than e at vertex **u** such that the cycle is gone and you have a tree again. Now you find again the most distant vertices u2, v2. Now you compute the maximal distance between the four vertices u1, u2, v1, v2 and this is your diameter in linear time.

This would improve you running time to *O*(n*k^2 + n^2)